# What is the correct way of declaring the type in an object where the key is a string and the value is an array of objects in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
let colors = {
    "blue" : [
        {
            title: "blue",
            summary : "blue is ...",
            image : "image of blue", // this is an optional option
            link : "https:// ..."
        }, 
        {
            title: "blue",
            summary : "blue is ...",
            link : "https:// ..."
        }
    ], 
    "yellow" : [{ ... }]
}
```

This is an example of the structure I want to type, but I'm having trouble with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take advantage of TS you will have to define a separate interface for your color property objects.

```
interface colorProp {
            title: string;
            summary : string;
            image? : string;
            link : string;
} ;


let colors : {
    [key : string] : colorProp[]
}= {
    "blue" : [
        {
            title: "blue",
            summary : "blue is ...",
            image : "image of blue", // this is an optional option
            link : "https:// ..."
        }, 
        {
            title: "blue",
            summary : "blue is ...",
            link : "https:// ..."
        }
    ], 
    "yellow" : [{ ... }]
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgQewDZqgBSmgB2QG8BYAKGSupqrGDAwgC5kBnMKUAcwG4Lag9gFcAtqLhQAnslYcuIPgKE1gE7hAD8s9px79KK6hlABrHfP0UAvsgMUKTMKkzY2OsoaoBtUxBlyeooAujroWLj4BN7BNgC8JMpUAEQARhjCEMk63km0nkbU9IwsyGkZWQA0eSpsYhLSOuWZyMDuAHSdydVeRmpwGk39g2gwyOmZ3cgA9NPIYAAWba3ucCDIhPRoIHAYGwRbIDVCJiDmrMkLYGAEbMyzyJ3tycdU1pXIr4m9KsVMFxMql8aHVxJIAmVAStHl0eoUqKdzmUrjc7g8ni8ftRrHlgh88skpBAMFgAO7ZVjeYgw9rIayxcg48gUIA)